# Facebook -> It looks like your account was sending out spam. We would like to help you secure your account. -> Leads to HTTP 500 page

Tags: facebook

**Update:**

Three new users have posted answers that simply says they have the same problem and no solution. If you are new to the site and think this question is useful click the up arrow to the left on desktop and above on mobile instead. I have also reported this as a bug directly to Facebook and Tweeted them. Lets hope this will be resolved soon if no work around is found.

Retweet or like then Facebook will see that more users have this problem:

https://twitter.com/Ogglas/status/1315275439850520578

Why answers that simply states "I have the same problem" is removed here:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

You can also report this to Facebook by creating a new account and then click on the arrow in the top right corner -> "Give Feedback" -> "Something went wrong" -> Select area `Log-in` and then explain what happened. You can also link to this question.

[image]

**Original:**

A friends personal Facebook account was hacked and a password reset has been performed.

After log in it looks like this:

> Review Recent Posts and Likes
>
> Hi , it looks like your account was sending out spam. We would
> like to help you secure your account. Please help us by making sure
> all recent likes and posts were made by you.

[image]

Clicking on Get Started leads to a `Sorry, something went wrong.` page and response code is HTTP 500. Tested with several browsers and same response every time.

[image]

Tested to reset via [messenger.com](https://www.messenger.com/) but it leads back to [facebook.com](https://www.facebook.com/).

[image]

Is the only alternative to wait for Facebook to fix this issue or is there anyway to bypass this step?

Comment: I saw there are many people facing this issue, so I made a petition:
https://www.ipetitions.com/petition/facebook-error-review-recent-posts-and-likes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter user @bengriffindor managed to get access to his Facebook account again after 14 days by submitting these forms:

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/357439354283890

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=179049432194862

Source:

https://twitter.com/bengriffindor/status/1322185910969131009

Answer (score 0):

You're in a "checkpoint loop". It's definitely a bug. It happened a few times earlier in the year when I got a checkpoint for suspicious actions. The "trick" I used was to send oneself a password reset, to cause the checkpoint flow to reset, and refresh the page after the checkpoint (if it 500s still). I'm not sure if this still works.

It would also help to update your question to show the list of network requests, not the static JS/CSS/PNG, the AJAX ones, leading up to and including the 500.

Comment: Using a new password reset did not work for my friend. It is a POST request to `https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/?next=https://www.facebook.com/login/?privacy_mutation_token=` with Form Data `submit[Get Started]: Get Started`. First step after login so there is really nothing to do what I can tell. Gonna try what the Twitter user @bengriffindor did in my answer.

Comment: Okay no problem. I can only know what I did based on experience, good luck.

Comment: Definitely worth a try. :)